# When to use 不是 + adj

Tags: adjectives

While I was studying, I came across this sentence.

> 如果她不是特别漂亮也没关系。

But I’m confused as to why 是 is there. I thought negation of adjectives should’nt be accompanied by 是. Could someone explain this please? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I’m confused as to why 是 is there. I thought negation of
>   adjectives should’nt be accompanied by 是. Could someone explain this
>   please?

First think the component as 是[other description] where [other description] is true. 是 is used to denote some description is true. Because [other description] is after 是, [other description] is true.

Second think another component as 不[other description] where [other description] is false. 不 is used to denote some description is false. Because [other description] is after 不, [other description] is false.

First point and second point exist independently. Although they exist independently, they can be used together.

Use "first point" first. think 是特別漂亮 as 是[特別漂亮](是[other description], where [other description] is 特別漂亮)(is especially pretty). 是 is used to denote [other description] is true so 特別漂亮(especially pretty) is true. You get that 是特別漂亮 means is especially pretty.

Then use "second point" , think 不是特別漂亮 as 不[是特别漂亮](不[other description], where [other description] is 是特别漂亮) (is not especially pretty). In this example 不 is used to denote [other description] is false so 是特别漂亮(is especially pretty) is false. You get 不是特別漂亮 means "is not especially pretty".

Answer (score 1):

"不是" is a set team for "is not". It doesn't negate the adjective. It is the negative form of the verb "是"(is)

- 她(是) = she (is)
- 她(不是) = she (isn't)
- 她(是)特别漂亮 = she (is) very pretty
- 她(不是)特别漂亮 = she (isn't) very pretty

~

不 = not

When we use 不 alone before an adjective, it modify the adjective by negate it. The subject 她 became the topic, and the negated adjective 不漂亮 became the comment

- 漂亮 = pretty
- 不漂亮 = not pretty
- 她(漂亮) = she, (pretty)
- 她(不漂亮) = she, (not pretty)
- 她(不漂亮但善良) = she, (not pretty, but kind)

Comment: Then is 她是漂亮 wrong but 她是特别漂亮 correct?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you can interpret 是 and 不是 as follows:

是 - It is the case that...

不是 - It is not the case that...

"如果她不是特别漂亮也没关系。" - It's OK if it is not the case that she is very pretty.

A： "你不喜欢红酒？”

B: 是。 (No, I don't like - Yes, it is the case that I don't like.）

B1: 不是。（But yes, I do like - No, it is not the case that I don't like.)